# MySQL Variable Returning Incorrect Value

Tags: mysql

### The Issue

I have a stored proc in a DB server that's bringing back a value of `5064803` when that record does not exist and the value should be `5064800` as per the query that builds the value of the variable.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the value being of the `FLOAT` data type and the value in the record of the table ending in a double-zero or what but I cannot figure it out easily.

The table data types match those from the sensors that are set but this particular value from this sensor never actually gets set to a data type and it's usually always either a 1-8 digit `INT` with no decimal but I'd like to keep the data types the same as the correlated sensor just in case.

I've broke down the proc and I'm able to recreate the problem easily so I will post the detail below for those that may be able to help me figure out the issue and any workaround, etc.

---

### The SQL Data

**Create Table**

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `number` (
  `TimeInt` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `TimeStr` datetime NOT NULL,
  `IsInitValue` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value` float NOT NULL,
  `IQuality` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_Times` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

**Insert Data**

```
INSERT INTO `Number` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1502618950','2017-08-13 10:09:10',1,5064800,0);
INSERT INTO `Number` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1502618796','2017-08-13 10:06:36',0,5064800,3);
INSERT INTO `Number` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1502617167','2017-08-13 09:39:27',1,5063310,0);
INSERT INTO `Number` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1502613355','2017-08-13 08:35:55',0,5063310,3);
INSERT INTO `Number` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1502612814','2017-08-13 08:26:54',1,0,0);
INSERT INTO `Number` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1502609015','2017-08-13 07:23:35',0,0,3);
```

**The SQL Query Breakdown**

```
SET @bStartTime = '2017-08-13 09:24:16';
SET @bEndTime = '2017-08-13 10:06:31';
SET @LastNumber = (SELECT Value FROM Number ORDER BY TimeStr DESC LIMIT 1); 
SET @NowNumber  = (SELECT Value FROM Number WHERE TimeStr BETWEEN @bStartTime AND @bEndTime ORDER BY TimeStr DESC LIMIT 1);

SELECT @NowNumber;
SELECT @LastNumber;
```

---

### Recreating the Issue

So based on **The SQL Query Breakdown** above, once all the data is in the table and then I run the queries within the `SELECT` queries alone within the `@NowNumber` and/or `@LastNumber` variables, I get the correct result of `5064800`. However, if I run the entire `SET` statements for both of those to have it set the query and then just do a `SELECT` of those variable, it brings back the wrong result of `5064803`.

So for example if I run `SELECT Value FROM Number ORDER BY TimeStr DESC LIMIT 1` then the correct value is returned. If I run `SET @LastNumber = (SELECT Value FROM Number ORDER BY TimeStr DESC LIMIT 1);` and then run `SELECT @LastNumber;` I get the incorrect value returned.

---

### Server System Specs

This particular **MySQL Server** is running the x86 version of `5.5.50` on **Windows Server 2008** with 144 GB of RAM for some quick specs.

---

### Question

- I'd like to know what is causing this, and if there is a workaround to the problem either with or without changing the data type of the column assuming that's the issue when it's returned as a variable rather than just a straight query result.

  - I'll be happy to disclose more technical specs of the environment if needed but I've included what I think it important for the question. Perhaps this is a version bug or there's something obvious that causes this that I cannot see easily so I'm hoping someone can help me with this or explain why this is or is not possible with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, declares can only be used in stored procedures in MySQL.  I found this article which may help.  It explains how MySQL rounds when storing digits and recommends using doubles.  Try changing your floats to doubles.

[MySql FLOAT datatype and problems with more then 7 digit scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898454/mysql-float-datatype-and-problems-with-more-then-7-digit-scale)